# Netlogo - Sandpile Model - update count - runtime Error

Tags: netlogo

At each tick i am asking each patch to update its count dependent on that of its 8 neighbours.  If more than 4 neighbours have a count more than or equal to 1 then they update by 1.  If more than 4 neighbours have a count less than or equal to 1 then the patch count should be set to 0.

When i run the code i get the following error:

"The >= operator can only be used on two numbers, two strings, or two agents of the same type, but not on a TRUE/FALSE and a number.error while patch 27 -22 running >= called by procedure SPREAD-ERRORS called by procedure GO"

```
to spread-errors ;; Errors spread prior to addition of random error
                 ;; This is dependent upon majority of neighbors with errors               
  ask patches [
    ifelse count neighbors with [n >= 1] > 4
    [update-n 1]
    [set n n = 0]
  ]  
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean `set n 0`, not `set n n = 0`.

But why is `set n n = 0` actually valid NetLogo syntax, and how did it end up leading to the error message you get?

Well, `n = 0` is a boolean expression whose value is either `true` or `false`. Then you're taking that value and storing it in n. The effect is as if you had written:

```
ifelse n = 0 [ set n true ] [ set n false ]
```

after this command runs, n holds a boolean. Then the next time `n >= 1` runs, you get the error message above, since n is no longer a number and can't be compared with 1.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  The code works perfectly well now!!